# Detecting a MEF assembly at runtime

Tags: c#, mef

I have a directory with many .dlls some of which are MEF plugins which I am loading using a `DirectoryCatalog` - for example:

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
```

This loads into the catalog all assemblies at hosts executing directory. However, I wish to only build a catalog of MEF assemblies (i.e. composable parts).

Is there a way to detect MEF assemblies?

Comment: Why don't you put MEF assemblies to a separate folder?

Comment: Could, but not an ideal solution...especially when plugins have dependent dlls that are expected to be in the same directory as the plugins running location

Comment: Well, all the software I use coming with plugins stores them in a subfolder 'plugins' or something like that. Thus I don't think it is a bad choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those assemblies without MEF parts do not have any effect on  `DirectoryCatalog.Parts`, so MEF already does the detection for you.

If you feel that the performance impact of scanning all assemblies for MEF parts is too high, then you can use a [search pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833475.aspx) to filter on the DLL name like this:

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    "*.plugins.dll");
```

Comment: Hmm...I like your solution but it's still not ideal. 
To address your first point- when you consequently construct a `CompositionContainer` off the assembly it will throw an exception for any non-mef assemblies....thus `DirectoryCatalog`'s detection capabilities don't serve the purpose

Comment: @aateeque: that's not the expected behavior. What kind of exception do you get?

Comment: yeah you are right, my apologies. `CompositionContainer` construction is fine...problem arises when a subsequent attempt is made to `GetExports` i.e. get the exported types in each assembly in the container. Does that make sense?

Comment: @aateeque: that still should not cause an exception, at least not just because the directory catalog contains an assembly without MEF parts. Though the first time it is called, `GetExports` *will* cause the types in all assemblies to be enumerated, which can result in `ReflectionTypeLoadException` if you have unloadable types. That's not really a MEF-specific problem though. It usually just means that you have a defunct assembly sitting in your build folder which references types that no longer exist. That's why I asked what kind of exception you get.

Comment: I get a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` when I do `GetExports<ICommand, IcommandMetadata>()`

Comment: @aateeque: in that case I would try to clean out your build folder. The exception will probably go away.

Comment: But that's the whole idea- a directory may contain MEF plugins or it may contain other assemblies. Just show me a list of ICommands available...moving to chat to discuss further

Answer (score 1):

Here's a class that you should be able to just drop in and use to fix the ReflectionTypeLoadException problem.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Your.Namespace
{
    public class SafeDirectoryCatalog : AggregateCatalog
    {
        public SafeDirectoryCatalog(string folderLocation)
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo(folderLocation);

            if (!di.Exists) throw new Exception("Folder not exists: " + di.FullName);

            var dlls = di.GetFileSystemInfos("*.dll");

            foreach (var fi in dlls)
            {
                try
                {
                    var ac = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFile(fi.FullName));
                    var parts = ac.Parts.ToArray(); // throws ReflectionTypeLoadException 
                    this.Catalogs.Add(ac);
                }
                catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
                {
                    //Swallow this exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cheers! this helped :)
example usage:

var catalog = new SafeDirectoryCatalog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.SatisfyImportsOnce(MyMEFCatalog.Instance);